# You were born in (the) winter: is the article necessary?

Tags: definite-article

> You were born in (the) winter.

I am interested in this particular case of using the article since someone's birth is often associated with a particular season of a particular year. Is the article necessary in such expressions? I'd like to have information on this case.

Answer (score 10):

Without special context describing a particular winter the definite article can be omitted. Apart from that in most cases it is a matter of which sounds best and your personal choice. In many contexts either will be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Another [viable possibility](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20winter%20time%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1945,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en) is

> You were born in the winter-time.

(or "winter time" without the hyphen)